# Set a state with user data getting getIdTokenResult ()

Tags: typescript, rxjs, firebase-authentication, reactive-programming, ngrx

I'm having trouble putting an object in and putting it in the state of my application.

I need to mount an object with the data returned from `firebase.user` and `user.getIdTokenResult(true)`.

**Example:**

```
userLogged = {
  uid: user.uid, 
  displayName: user.displayName
  admin: false,
};

const token = await user.getIdTokenResult (true);
userLogged.admin = token.claims.admin;
```

The logic is similar to the one above, however I need to do this using only the Rxjs operators so that I can seclude this object in the state of my application.

**@Effect**

```
@Effect()
getUser$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(auth.AuthActionTypes.GET_USER),
    switchMap(() => this.authService.getUser().pipe(
        map(user => {

            const userLogged = {
                uid: user.uid,
                displayName: user.displayName,
                admin: false,
            }

            // **** i need call user.getIdTokenResult() ******
            // and get claims.admin and assign to userLogged object admin.

            // authState = {
            //    uid: user.uid,
            //    displayName: user.displayName,
            //    admin: true, // true or false
            // }

            return new auth.Authenticated(userLogged);
        }),
        catchError((err => of(new auth.AuthError(err))))
    )
```

I'm still adapting myself using reactive programming using Rxjs, so I'm having a hard time merging encapsulated Observables data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.map()` to "retain" the values of `user` object in your `authService.getUser()` result. It works albeit being dirty.

```
@Effect()
getUser$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .pipe(
        ofType(auth.AuthActionTypes.GET_USER),
        switchMap(() => this.authService.getUser()),
        switchMap(user => user.getIdTokenResult().pipe(map(claims => ({claims, user}))), //map the user to "retain"
            switchMap(({claims, user}) => {
                const userLogged = {
                    uid: user.uid,
                    displayName: user.displayName,
                    admin: claims.admin,
                };
                return new auth.Authenticated(userLogged);
            }),
            catchError(err => of(new auth.AuthError(err)))))
```

If you want to retrain more values, suggest that you look into `Subjects` so that it is cleaner (and the correct way of doing it).

Comment: in the last switchMap() I put map() and it worked for me, Thanks!